# e.Row.Cells[x] not indexing correctly

Tags: .net, data-binding, gridview

I currently have this gridview OnRowDataBound method in my asp.net app:

```
protected void gvwStatus_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string excsCost = e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();
        //do stuff//
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
                                  <asp:GridView ID="gvwStatus" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                                        AllowPaging="True" BackColor="Control" OnSorting="gvw_OnSorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvwStatus_PageIndexChanging"
                                        OnRowDataBound="gvwStatus_OnRowDataBound" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                        Width="98%" PageSize="100" Style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item" SortExpression="ITEM_NO">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnItemNo" runat="server" CssClass="app_hyperlink" Text='<%#Eval("ITEM_NO") %>'
                                                        OnCommand="lbtnItemNo_OnClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ITEM_NO") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_OBS_STATUS" HeaderText="Obs Status" SortExpression="ITEM_OBS_STATUS" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MIP_NO" HeaderText="MIP" SortExpression="MIP_NO" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LOT_FROM_EFF_DATE" HeaderText="Chgovr Date" SortExpression="LOT_FROM_EFF_DATE" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TRGT_CHGOVR_DATE" HeaderText="Target Date" SortExpression="TRGT_CHGOVR_DATE" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Excess Cost" SortExpression="EXCS_ITEM_COST_TOT">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblExcessCostStatus" runat="server" CssClass="app_label" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("EXCS_ITEM_COST_TOT")) %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SENT_TS" HeaderText="Sent to Plants/Vndrs" SortExpression="SENT_TS" />
                                        </Columns>
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gvLinkNoUnderline" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

The indexing is not functioning correctly here. For my string excsCost, I specify that I want the value from index 3 (or cell 4) but I'm getting the value from index 5 (cell 6). When I specify index 2, I get the value from index 0. Seems to be completely misaligned.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Can you show your GridView markup?

Comment: I don't know GridView, but with DataGridView (winforms), if the columns have been reordered at runtime, the display indices won't match up with the column indices. Could that be it? Could you use column name instead of index?

Comment: No, unfortunately. You cannont reference gridview columns by string name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `ItemTmplate` so you can get the Control programmatically and manipulate it in your code

```
   protected void gvwStatus_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {


      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         Label lblExcsCost = new Label();
         lblExcsCost = e.Row.FindControl("lblExcessCostStatus") as Label;
         string excsCost = lblExcsCost.Text();
      }
    }
```